# Finding highest point in a a curve generated following two rect lines

Tags: javascript, math, graph, jsxgraph

I'm using JSXGraph to graph two rect lines, in the intersection I need to create a curve following the two lines and connecting the point B with the point C, then I need to find the highest point of that curve. There are any approach that I could use?

[image]

Comment: There can be infinite curves that connect points B and C. How will you decide which one you need?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, the problem as stated has not a unique solution. One possibility would be to choose one of the many spline curves. I would propose a very simple approach using highschool mathematics: Take a polynomial *f* of degree three which runs through the points *B* and *C* and whose derivative at B is equal to the slope of the line *AB* and whose derivative at *C* is equal to the slope of the line *CD*.

To make things easier, we assume that the x-coordinate of B is 0, and the x-coordinate of C is 1. Further, we denote the slope of the line *AB* with *s1* and the slope of line *CD* with *s2*. For the general solution we will have to multiply *s1* and *s2* later on by *C_x - B_x*.

Now, we have to compute the parameters *a,b,c,d* of the polynomial

> f(x) = ax^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d.

This can be done by noting that

- *f(0) = B_y*
- *(f(1) = a + b + c + d*
- *f'(0) = c = s_1*
- *f'(1) = 3a + 2b + c = s_1*,

see the function `f` in the code below. When we know the polynomial *f*,
the maximum of *f* can be determined easily by computing a root of the derivative

> *f'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c*

Here is the code:

```
var A, B, C, D, l1, l2, f, g, maximum, curve, E;

A = board.create('point', [-4,-2]);
B = board.create('point', [-2,2]);
C = board.create('point', [1, 2]);
D = board.create('point', [3, 0]);

l1 = board.create('line', [A, B]);
l2 = board.create('line', [C, D]);

f = function(x) {
  var dx = C.X() - B.X(),
    s1 = l1.getSlope() * dx,
    s2 = l2.getSlope() * dx,
    a, b, c, d;

  d = B.Y();
  c = s1;
  a = s2 - s1 - 2 * (C.Y() - c - d);
  b = C.Y() - c - d - a;
  return a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d;
};

g = function(x) {
  return f((x - B.X()) / (C.X() - B.X()));
};

maximum = function() {
  var dx = C.X() - B.X(),
    s1 = l1.getSlope() * dx,
    s2 = l2.getSlope() * dx,
    a, b, c, d, x1, x2, x, dis;
  d = B.Y();
  c = s1;
  a = s2 - s1 - 2 * (C.Y() - c - d);
  b = C.Y() - c - d - a;

  dis = 4 * b * b - 12 * a * c;
  x1 = (-2 * b + Math.sqrt(dis)) / (6 * a);
  x2 = (-2 * b - Math.sqrt(dis)) / (6 * a);
  if (6 * a * x1 + 2 * b < 0) {
    x = x1;
  } else {
    x = x2;
  }
  x = x * (C.X() -  B.X()) + B.X();
  return [x, g(x)];
};

curve = board.create('functiongraph', [g], {strokeCOlor: 'red', strokeWidth: 3});
E = board.create('point', [maximum]);
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/bv5mgy7k/8/